# Is there a way to make Animations not Halt Flutter driver?

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

[`FlutterDriver` from `flutter_driver`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_driver/flutter_driver-library.html) will **pause** all actions until there is no animation playing anymore.

My UI involves looping animations and I want to tap something in my integration tests while such an animation is playing.
Once I enter a screen that has a looping animation that will not stop unless there is a tap input, `FlutterDriver` will simply **time out** as it waits for the animation to finish (which will consequently never happen in my integration test).

Basically, all actions like [`driver.tap`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_driver/FlutterDriver/tap.html) will by default wait for all animations (at least created by an [`AnimationController`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/AnimationController-class.html)) before they are taken.

```dart
test('stop looping animation', () async {
  // Navigated to a screen with a looping animation before that.
  await driver.tap(find.byValueKey('stop_looping_animation')); // FlutterDriver will time out here.
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`FlutterDriver.runUnsynchronized`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_driver/FlutterDriver/runUnsynchronized.html):

```dart
test('stop looping animation', () async {
  await driver.runUnsynchronized(() async {
    await driver.tap(find.byValueKey('stop_looping_animation'));
  });
});
```

Had a similar problem, this comment helped: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/34503#issuecomment-503545683